# jquery safari issue on windows operating system

Tags: jquery

The jquery function for file upload works fine in all browsers except in windows safari browser.

I have requirement like, when click on link i call file upload on an input file which is hidden using CSS and the code is as following

```
$("#select-file").click(function(){
        $("#input_type_file").trigger('click');
        return false;

    });
```

What needs to be changed here ???

Comment: Have you got your own handler on 'input_type_file' click or you are looking for triggering the native event (open file dialog) of an input type file?

Comment: yes i am calling the native event. I mean i want the file dialog to open for input type file

Comment: This works in Safari 5.x: http://jsfiddle.net/d3p45/   Which version of safari are you using?

Comment: windows OS - safari 5.6

Comment: But wait: isn't it currently 5.1.7 lastest version available for windows OS? Or i missing something?!

Comment: So, is the jsfiddle i provide works for you? I tested it in win7 and works

Comment: with that it works...is there any other jquery conflict the reason ???? But i wonder y only for one OS and one browser

Comment: There is one for sure: is your input type file hidden using CSS?   << But i wonder y only for one OS and one browser>>  For security purpose!

Comment: yes input type file is hidden

Comment: Hey mate sorry about it..but i was not knowing the hidden would cost this much....its working now...

Comment: no problem but the more info you give, the easiest it is to help, hope you understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a workaround, because Safari under win OS doesn't allow to trigger native click event on input type file which is hidden from user:

instead of `display:none` use this:

```
#input_type_file{position:absolute;left:-9999px}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mumqg/